# Impossible to connect bluetooth mouse to rapsberry pi 3 b

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

I bought a bluetooth mouse (Logitech M590) hoping I could use it for both my Windows 10 laptop, and my Raspberry Pi 3 B. I've managed to connect it to Windows 10 without the dongle, but there is a significant time lag issue.

Then, I've tried to connect this mouse to my Pi. I am using the command line and bluetoothctl. It pairs and connects successfully, but when when I use the trust command, it shuts down `bluetoothd`, and I have to manually start it again with

```
sudo systemctl start bluetooth
```

Here's an image showing what happens when I use the command

trust xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

https://ibb.co/dLp9H9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could use M590 with the following command.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=171456

> open terminal window and type the following lines:
>
> ```
> sudo hciconfig hci0 down
>
> sudo hciconfig hci0 up
>
> bluetoothctl
> ```

Pairing, connecting, trusting, please reboot.

Comment: This method is depreciated; see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth#Configuration

Comment: This also works with the Raspberry Pi 4 as well.